# Create a master-detail relationship between a custom object and Opportunity - upon creation of the custom object

Tags: workflow, custom-object, process-builder, opportunity, trigggers

I thought I would have found several previous answers to guide me, but I haven’t.

Each quarter I want to track a set of KPIs for a deal.  I have therefore created a Salesforce custom object called ReportingQuarter which holds my KPIs for a given quarter.  My deals are represented by the standard Salesforce Opportunity object.

My system is made up of a WordPress frontend and a Salesforce (Lightning) backend.  The input of the KPIs takes place on the frontend and then is sent to Salesforce in the form of a request to create a ReportingQuarter.  At the point the ReportingQuarter is created in Salesforce, I want to attach it to the Opportunity to which it relates.  As I understand it, I need to create a master-detail relationship between the Opportunity (parent) and the ReportingQuarters (children) - there will be multiple ReportingQuarters per Opportunity.

I am new to Salesforce.  My original plan was to create a trigger, however given the comments on my previous iteration of this question, there is a suggestion a workflow rule or the Process Builder would also work.

Any specific guidance as to how to achieve want I am trying to, would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's  not clear why a trigger is needed here. You can create master-detail objects from the UI, or using declarative functionality like workflow rules or Process Builder.

Comment: Is it should run automatically in the end of month? Or is there a visualforce page to call the process?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Sorry, I probably should have mentioned.  The process of creating ReportingQuarters is taking place outside of Salesforce - via a WordPress frontend.  Also, the creation can happen at any point and not just at month/quarter end.  @DavidReed I am new to Salesforce, so if you think a workflow rule or using Process Builder is preferable, I am happy to go with that - I probably would still need a little guidance.  I did have a look at the Process Builder, but I couldn’t seem to get it to work with more than one object.  FYI I am using Salesforce Sales Cloud Lightning.

Comment: @rtd2 It sounds like you are in the design phase with an integrated system. It may be difficult to form a question that is answerable within StackExchange's guidelines, and you may need to work directly with someone with Salesforce experience. That said, please edit your question to clarify the entire flow of data and targeted functionality - this is very case-specific.

Comment: @DavidReed I have edited my question and title, as requested.  Thanks.

Comment: Your question is worded like you want to create an entirely new custom object for each new quarter in the future. Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: Implementation details aside, what is the logic for determining which Opportunity a given ReportingQuarter record should be associated with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this relationship may not be able to be master-detail: detail objects cannot exist without a master assigned, so your incoming (unassigned) `ReportingQuarter__c` objects can't be details. You'll possibly need to create a lookup relationship, depending on exactly how you execute the assignment solution.

Fundamentally, what your solution will need to do upon the insertion of a `ReportingQuarter__c` object is locate the corresponding Opportunity and populate that Opportunity's Salesforce ID in the `ReportingQuarter__c`'s lookup field.

I'm assuming that it is not possible to populate the Salesforce Id or an External Id for the Opportunity on the incoming data from WordPress. If that were possible, that would obviate the need for code on the Salesforce side, and would permit the use of a master-detail relationship.

The exact details of how to do this depend on what data points are available on your `ReportingQuarter__c` and Opportunity that would show that the one belongs to the other. However, this is achievable using both programmatic functionality with a trigger (query for Opportunity, populate Ids, update records) or via a Process Builder + Flow declarative approach. The decision of which to use is dependent both on your comfort level and technical resources available and upon expected data volume and performance needs. If you are expecting very high volume (thousands of incoming records), a properly bulkified trigger would *likely* be a more performant choice.

The implementation details must be left up to you. There's great Trailhead resources available on how to build triggers and on Process Builder/Flow, which can help form more specific questions on which StackExchange might provide more help.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  I landed up doing as you suggested – creating a look-up field on the `ReportingQuarter__c` Salesforce custom object and then populating it with the Salesforce Opportunity ID on the WordPress side.